# Entity form calculator in Drupal

Tags: forms, entities

I was wondering, is there anything like webform calculator for entity forms?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit? Entity forms use CCK fields, so you could run the fields through a view and do the math there?

Comment: Below is a very detailed tutorial to help you [Calculate Field Values Using Computed Field in Drupal 7](http://miss-hana.com/calculate-field-values-using-computed-field-in-drupal-7/) , and on bottom you will find the module and snippets you need to do it, i hope i helped.

Comment: What I want is, I have an entity form where some calculations are needed based on previous field within form itself without page refresh before saving a form.
For eg, I have field A , field B and field C in a form, value of field C = value of field A + value of field B.
I want this to happen when user enters data in form, this operation should be valid while creating and editing of a form as well

Comment: This does after saving.
What I want is, I have an entity form where some calculations are needed based on previous field within form itself without page refresh before saving a form. For eg, I have field A , field B and field C in a form, value of field C = value of field A + value of field B. I want this to happen when user enters data in form, this operation should be valid while creating and editing of a form as well

Comment: Maybe do this with jquery instead? Have a look at https://forum.jquery.com/topic/calculation-on-form-fields Just add three fields, and get jquery to populate the third field using values entered in real time from the first two. Dont forget $ is undefined in Drupal, so wrap it in jQuery